# Nginx returns 404 Not Found except index page

Tags: php, laravel, api, nginx, deployment

[image: this is what i am getting in the error log]

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name avadore.my.id;
    root /var/www/avadore.my.id/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Basically this is the conf file and I tried many solutions from the internet and didnt find a solution but basically i changed the  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; to  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args; and to 404 but still didnt work. Appreciate any help

Comment: It should be not `/index.php?$is_args$args` but `/index.php$is_args$args`, however this isn't a cause of the error, and your current config looks ok. What do you get in nginx error log? Are you completely sure that it is exactly this server block who handles the request? What do you mean by "index page"? Is it a laravel index page?

Comment: The index is the http://ipaddress/ but when i type in http://ipaddress/api/user it s giving me 404 error.. i edited and showed the error log

Comment: Please, do not use screenshots to show text messages, use markdown-formatted blocks instead. I don't see any 404-related messages from nginx; your error may come from the laravel app itself, however I can't tell you for sure and I don't know how laravel apps can be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is that my laravel version was 9 but i think it is only compatible with php version 8 but mines was version 7 so upgarding the php solves the problem thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).